# I want to sort the element of array

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose I have the array as follows

```
var array=[3,4,5,5,5,6,8,3,12,1,1,1];
```

Then the result should be

```
array=[5,1,3,4,6,8,12];
```

Required implementation in JavaScript or nodejs

Comment: Please [add the code you've written](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the problem you've got with it. SO doesn't write code for you.

Answer (score 3):

I used a combination of [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy) and plain JavaScript array methods in this [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/xinuko/edit?html,js,console):

```
var arr = [3,4,5,5,5,6,8,3,12,1,1,1];

var sorted = _.sortBy(_.toPairs(arr.reduce(function(agg, curr) {
  agg[curr] = agg[curr] ? agg[curr] + 1 : 1;

  return agg;
}, {})), function(pair) {
  return -pair[1];
}).map(function(pair) {
  return pair[0];
});

console.log(sorted); // => ["1", "5", "3", "4", "6", "8", "12"]
```

However, the ordering of `"5"` and `"1"` is different that the ordering of the `3,4,6,8,12`, because the sort order wasn't specified for numbers that have identical counts.

What the above does is created a map of `number=>count` (e.g. `{ "1": 3, "5": 3 }`), and then pairs them as tuples (since objects can't be sorted deterministically in JavaScript: `[["1", 3], ["5", 3]]`). Then, we simply sort the collection of tuples based on the count, and map over the collection of tuples to return just the number (e.g. `["1", "5", /* etc. */ ]`).

Answer (score 3):

```js
var array = [3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 8, 3, 12, 1, 1, 1];

var obj = {};

array.forEach(e => obj[e] = obj[e] + 1 || 1);

var sorted = Object.keys(obj)
    .map(e => ({ n: e, times: obj[e] }))
    .sort((a, b) => b.times - a.times)
    .map(e => e.n);

document.write(sorted);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it: 
JSBIN: https://jsbin.com/josuwir/1/edit?js,console

```
var array=[3,4,5,5,5,6,8,3,12,1,1,1];

var c = array.reduce(function(a, b) {
  a[b] = ++a[b] || 1;
  return a;
}, {});


var keys = Object.keys(c);


var nn = keys.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (c[a] < c[b]) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
}).map(function(a) {return Number(a)});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function sortArray(array) { 

    var reducedArray = array.filter(function(item, pos) { //A copy without duplicates
       return array.indexOf(item) == pos;
    })

    var elementFreq = {} //Object that contains element frequencies
    for (var i=0; i<reducedArray.length; i++) {
        var count = 0;
        for (var j=0; j<array.length; j++) {
            if (array[j] == reducedArray[i]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        elementFreq[array[i]] = count;
    }

    function compare(a,b) { //compares the frequency of two elements
        return elementFreq[b]-elementFreq[a]
    }

    reducedArray.sort(compare) //sorts reducedArray based using compare function

    return reducedArray 
}
```

Comment: This is understandable code but unnecessarily inefficient. You don't want to be running over the entire array every time you compare two items, that's for sure.

Comment: @Harangue You're right, thanks for the feedback. I edited my code to store the element frequencies before comparing.